# How do i get the text in jsoup link?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am parsing an html page using jsoup. Here is what i did so far:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=141_77").get();

Element page_clips = doc.getElementById("page_clips");

Element page_clip_content = page_clips.getElementById("content");
Elements allProductPricesOnPage = page_clip_content.getElementsByClass("price");
```

now, when i write:

```
allProductNamesOnPage.get(0);
```

it returns me the following:

```
<div class="name">
<a href="http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/index.php? 
route=product/product&amp;path=141_77&amp;product_id=4309"> here is the text</a>
</div>
```

What i want to do is, i want to get the "here is the text" part of that object. Can anyone help me with his?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to iterate over the `Elements` you have gathered and print their prices one by one:

```
Elements allProductPricesOnPage = page_clip_content
                .getElementsByClass("price");
for (Element el : allProductPricesOnPage) {
    System.out.println(el.text());
}
```

Gives,

```
19.99 TL KDV Dahil
9.99 TL KDV Dahil
14.99 TL KDV Dahil
```

What it does is, you are selecting `Elements` which implements `Iterator` (see javadoc [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html)), which gives you an access to individual `Element` objects within your collection.

Each of these `Element` objects which are repeating within your `HTML` have relevant information you want to extract.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract only the text, you can call the `text()` method:

```
String text = allProductNamesOnPage.get(0).text();
```

This method gets the text of an Element and its combined children. So if you want to ensure that you are only extracting text from the a element, call `text()` on the first child element:

```
String text = allProductNamesOnPage.get(0).child(0).text();
```

See here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html